# Timestamp postgres angularjs nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, postgresql

I'm having troubles on display graphs in AngularJS. I have my backend written in nodeJS where I have an aggregator as a buffer with data received by netdata, where I'm inserting data to insert in BD. But in the meantime, I'm doing this with a cron.

With a new client request I need another cron to write for the same BD and use the same aggregator but the structure is different, I'm not using netdata and I do all the changes but the problem is the timestamp inserted is different.

For example,

First Cron: 2017-07-12 15:31:28+01
Second Cron: 2017-07-12 15:16:21.335547+01  (On insert i use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

And maybe this is colliding in AngularJS... Anyone have an idea to insert in the format "2017-07-12 15:31:28+01" on my bd? My timestamp field is a timestamp with timezone.

If I comment the second cron the other graphs display ok

AgregateDatabase:

```
AgregateDatabase.prototype.addRow = function (dbConnection, data) {
    createLog('info', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), data.device_id, 'addRow','inicio');
    createLog('debug', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), data.device_id, 'addRow','type', data.type);


    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pg.connect(dbConnection, function (err, client, done) {
            if (err) {
                createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), data.device_id, 'addRow', err);
                reject(err);
                return
            }

            if(data.type==='probing_live' || data.type==='probing_repeated' || data.type==='probing_passBy'){
                    createLog('debug', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), data.device_id, 'addRow','data', data);

                client.query("INSERT INTO default_dataset (id, timestamp, agregation_period, medium, maximum, minimum, sum, type, device_id, network_id, organization_id, labels) \
                VALUES ($1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11)",
                    [data.id, data.agregation_period, data.medium, data.maximum, data.minimum, data.sum, data.type, data.device_id, data.network_id, data.organization_id, data.labels],
                    function (err, result) {
                        done();
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("probing addRow errrrrrrro");
                            createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), data.device_id, 'probing addRow error', err);
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log("probing addRow row added ", JSON.stringify(result));
                            createLog('info', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), data.device_id, 'probing addRow row added');
                            resolve(result.rows);
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                client.query("INSERT INTO default_dataset (id, timestamp, agregation_period, medium, maximum, minimum, sum, type, device_id, network_id, organization_id, labels) \
                    VALUES ($1, to_timestamp($2), $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12)",
                        [data.id, data.timestamp, data.agregation_period, data.medium, data.maximum, data.minimum, data.sum, data.type, data.device_id, data.network_id, data.organization_id, data.labels],
                        function (err, result) {
                            done();
                            if (err) {
                                console.log("probing addRow errrrrrrro");
                                createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), data.device_id, 'probing addRow error', err);
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log("probing addRow row added ", JSON.stringify(result));
                                createLog('info', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), data.device_id, 'probing addRow row added');
                                resolve(result.rows);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what's BD? where exactly is your problem? displaying the date or inserting it into your BD? are you getting any errors? refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question

Comment: I'm inserting the data ok but the timestamp saved for the type "probing_" is differente as i said before and that can be the reason all the graphs stops showing ok... I dont know

Answer (score 0):

Try to truncate current_timestamp like this:

```
INSERT INTO default_dataset (....)
                VALUES ($1, DATE_TRUNC('second',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) .....
```